# HeatnGlo Cerona-36

Tags: fireplace

This unit is six years old. The end of last season(2018) the flame began to rais and lower on its own. This year I’m unable to light the fireplace at all. Any and all help greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What happens when you try to light the flame; can you hear gas? Have you tried contacting the manufacturer? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: If it lights and then immediately goes out when you release the knob, chances are your flame sensor is either bad or needs adjusted. If it won't light at all, you either have no/insufficient gas flow/pressure or a bad igniter. Is the igniter battery-sourced? My guess is the flame-sensor based on your description of last season's behavior.